# Getting errors stray ‘\342’ and ‘\200’ and ‘\214’

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I'm trying to write a program for a simple game, but I am getting errors, stray ‘\342’ and ‘\200’ and ‘\214’, using g++ and gedit in [Ubuntu 13.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29) (Saucy Salamander).

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

char all_d()
{
    return 'D';
}

int main()
{
    bool more = true;
    while ( more )
    {
        cout << "enter C to cooperate, D to defect, Q to quit\n";
        char player_choice;
        cin >>‌ player_choice;

        if ( player_choice != 'C' || player_choice != 'D' || player_choice != 'Q' )
        {
            cout << "Illegal input.\nenter an other\n";
            cin >> player_choice;
        }

        char  cpu_choice = all_d();

        cout << "player's choice is " << player_choice << endl;
        cout << "cpu's choice is " << cpu_choice << endl;
    }

    if ( player_choice == 'Q' )
    {
        cout << "Game is Over!\n";
        more = false;
    }
}
```

and terminal output is:

```
IPD.cpp:18:3: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
   cin >>‌ player_choice;
   ^
IPD.cpp:18:3: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
IPD.cpp:18:3: error: stray ‘\214’ in program
IPD.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
IPD.cpp:29:47: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
   cout << "cpu's choice is " << cpu_choice << end;
                                               ^
IPD.cpp:32:7: error: ‘player_choice’ was not declared in this scope
  if ( player_choice == 'Q' )
       ^
```

I even tried to to compile this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a;
    cin >>‌ a;
}
```

and the terminal again says:

```
a.cpp:8:2: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
  cin >>‌ a;
  ^
a.cpp:8:2: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
a.cpp:8:2: error: stray ‘\214’ in program
```

How can I fix this?

Note that I installed Ubuntu last night.

Comment: `cout << ... << end`? replace with `endl`

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: Try using an editor that doesn't add silly characters to your source code. Or at least use an editor that **shows** you the silly characters when they are there.

Comment: 342 200 214 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0x8C (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+200C ([ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)).

Comment: @john: It may not be the editor, but caused by copying the code from a web page, say a blog post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using a [Zero Width Non Joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) character after the `>>` in your code. This is a Unicode character that is encoded in UTF-8 as three characters with values 0xE2, 0x80, and 0x8C (or in base 8, \342, \200, and \214). This probably happened because you copy and pasted some code from a document (HTML web page?) that uses those special characters.

The C++ language requires that the whole program uses mostly the ASCII encoding, except for the content of strings or character literals (that may be in a implementation-dependent encoding). So to fix your problem, make sure that you only use simple ASCII space, quotes, double quotes and not smart characters.

Comment: *"except for the content of strings or character literals "*  C++ also allows non-ASCII characters in comments.

Comment: FWIW, `\342` for me is the fancy quote character `’` (not the ASCII single quote `'`)

Answer (score 2):

```
cin >>‌ a;
```

I've copy-pasted that into Python and found out that between `>>` and the following space there are 3 characters: `\xe2` `\x80` `\x8c`. Decode them as UTF-8 and you get a [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://codepoints.net/U+200c).

How it got into your code, I don't know. Find it out. Anything interesting about the editor you're using? Your keyboard layout?

Comment: A very common reason is copying code from web pages, PDF documents, and through chat (e.g. Skype Chat) (formatted text sources).

Comment: Re *"I've copy-pasted that into Python"*: What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what was said you have also one more error related to using variable player_choice outside its scope.

```
while ( more )
{
    cout << "enter C to cooperate, D to defect, Q to quit\n";
    char player_choice;
    // other stuff
}

if ( player_choice == 'Q' )
{
    cout << "Game is Over!\n";
    more = false;
}
```

It was defined in the while loop before the code snippet above and was destroyed after exiting the loop. So using it in this if statement is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code snippet, completely unmodified, and found that you have a seriously funky space character after `cin >>`. Look below:

[image]

Get rid of the `<200c>`, and you should be able to compile just fine. Depending on the editor you're using, you may or may not be able to see it printed like this.

Comment: what is "<2000>" in there? and what about the second error in if?

Comment: It's the way my editor represents a zero-width non joiner character.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm

As far as the rest of your errors go, you have a few syntax things that need to be fixed (like, what is `end`?) but this one is the biggest problem cause it's hard to see.

Comment: What is your editor?

Comment: @PeterMortensen at the time i answered this, most likely mvim